# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am trying to code an application that monitors sms messages. I want to start a service from my main Activity class, but the service doesn't start for some reason. I think there might be a problem with how I declared my service in the manifest file or how I call it from my activity.
Here is a part of my activity Code:

```
public class TablighBlockActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private ToggleButton toggEnable;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (loadState("running")==false){startService(new Intent(this, SMSMonitor.class));}
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and Here is a part of my Service class:

```
public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context,SMSMonitor.class);
    i.setClass(context, SMSMonitor.class);
    context.startService(i);
```

And here is my manifest File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tabligh.block"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name="SMSMonitor">  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action> 
            </intent-filter>  

        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".TablighBlockActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".SMSMonitor"
                                    android:process=":smsmonitor"
                                    ></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the error log:

```
06-22 13:46:14.649: W/dalvikvm(1013): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
06-22 13:46:14.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service tabligh.block.SMSMonitor: java.lang.ClassCastException: tabligh.block.SMSMonitor
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2449)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:112)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: tabligh.block.SMSMonitor
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2446)
06-22 13:46:15.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     ... 10 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the permissions required for the service to your manifest file?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException due to permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

you are SMSMonitor which is a BroadcastReceiver not Service

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,SMSMonitor.class);
    i.setClass(context, SMSMonitor.class);
    context.startService(i);
```

Comment: Thanks this should be the cause of the problem. When I remove the services tag form the manifest file and the start.Service(i) part, the application seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

`tabligh.block.SMSMonitor` is receiver and service in your manifest file ?

i think it should be Service.and extends BroadCastReceiver to SMSMonitor.

```
 <receiver android:name="SMSMonitor"> **and**  

   <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".SMSMonitor"
                                    android:process=":smsmonitor"
                                    ></service>
```

**AND**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,SMSMonitor.class);
//i.setClass(context, SMSMonitor.class);<<Remove this line no need...
context.startService(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes come across weird errors by not starting `onCreate()` with the standard `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()`.

And like others have said, make sure that you have added the `Service` to your `Manifest file`.  This and forgetting to add Activities after I create them are my biggest mistake!

edit: Sorry, somehow missed all the `Manifest` code you put there.